# Default margin when converting html to pdf

Tags: c#, itext7, html-to-pdf

I have function like this that convert html to pdf:

```
private Stream BuildPdf(string html)
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);
            pdfWriter.SetCloseStream(false);
            var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);

            var fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider();
            fontProvider.AddDirectory("Path/To/Fots/Folder"));
            var converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
            converterProperties.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);
            
            var doc = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(html, pdfDocument, converterProperties);

            doc.Close();
            pdfWriter.Flush();

            NumberPages(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream;
        }
```

Example of html:

```
<html>
  <style>
      body {
        /*A4*/
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: Helvetica
            position: relative;
        }
        .content {
         margin: 20mm; 
        }
    </style>
      <head><title>Test</title></head>
       <body>
         <p class="content">HeadEng</p>
            $(Content) //Is replaced to actual contend by code
       </body>
</html>
```

In resulting pdf I see "Default margins"
[Example of margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBw3c.png)
I need a way to delete these default margins, empty space between text and borders of document

I tried to used doc.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0), expected to not have margins, actual result is nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
@page {
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
```